# Google map markers showing wrong positions

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I need to show some markers on a google map. I am using the standard google code provided in the [sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations-iteration)

```
var neighborhoods = [
{ lat: 17.009743, lng: 81.7738098 }, //devi chowk
{ lat: 17.007859, lng: 81.78112 }, //hdfc bank - danavaipeta, 
{ lat: 17.0051851, lng: 81.7763473 }, //swamy theater 
{ lat: 17.0095814, lng: 81.781733 } //baskin robbins 
];

      var markers = [];
      var map;

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 12,
          center: {lat: 52.520, lng: 13.410}
        });
      }

      function drop() {
        clearMarkers();
        for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
          addMarkerWithTimeout(neighborhoods[i], i * 200);
        }
      }

      function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
          }));
        }, timeout);
      }

      function clearMarkers() {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          markers[i].setMap(null);
        }
        markers = [];
      }
```

I open google maps and search for the location and from the url i find the latitude and longitude and use in the code/

I am getting the animation drop and four markers but the position they are showing is an error (around 500 meters towards west). this error is common across all the markers.

On the google maps I get the correct positions (obviously) but when I use the same coordinates in my application i get the error.

see the below screenshot

[image: blue circle is the correct position and red flags are my markers]

can someone help me understand what could be the issue?

Comment: i have no idea, but probably sth like this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/measuring-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates in the Google Maps URL are the center of the map, not the location of the location you searched for.

HDFC Bank (on my computer): 
https://www.google.com/maps/search/hdfc+bank,+danavaipeta/@17.0118051,81.7820404,16z/data=!3m1!4b1

coordinates in URL: 17.0118051,81.7820404

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=(17.0118051,81.7820404)&geocode=1&zoom=16&addr2=hdfc+bank,+danavaipeta&place=2

coordinates of HDFC Bank from the Places API: 17.007877, 81.7834242

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you open google maps, you should click on the location, and then click share.  For[image]

You will see the lat,lng for the location